# Toggle button not working as per conditions

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have a toggle button to play and stop .mp3 , music got stop but when I unchecked the button it wont start mp3 again.

Here is my code:

```
 tg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clicks
                if (tg.isChecked())
                { // Checked - Pause icon visible
                  // tg.setBackgroundDrawable(d)
                    try {
                        mp_tick.stop();
                        // mp_tick.pause();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else { // Unchecked - Play icon visible
                    try {
                        // mp_tick.seekTo(0);
                        mp_tick.prepare();
                        mp_tick.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

my log is.

```
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFF8E
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at com.example.iamgraduate.Questions$2.onClick(Questions.java:101)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
01-30 21:41:00.408: W/System.err(27777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 21:41:00.418: W/System.err(27777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 21:41:00.418: W/System.err(27777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-30 21:41:00.418: W/System.err(27777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-30 21:41:00.418: W/System.err(27777):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line number `101` ?

Comment: // mp_tick.seekTo(0); this is line 101 @ρяσѕρєяK